Power BI Rest API Received odata.count = 0
i have a problem wtih the access token.
I try get groups and access_token on learn.microsoft.com it's successfully and received 15 items
but when i try get token with C#, i can get but i try that token on postman i receiving "return @odata.count = 0" message.
my C# codes :
`string tenantSpeceficAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + _tenantId + "/oauth2/v2.0/token";

var appConfidential = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_clientID)
.WithClientSecret(_clientSecret)
.WithAuthority(tenantSpeceficAuthority)
.WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
.Build();

string[] scopes = { "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default" };

var authResult = appConfidential.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
_accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;`

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thank you
DoDe
i was expected received 15 items
